# How to avoid use dependencies again (Android)?

Tags: android, maven

I've created an Android library with Studio and this library needs some 3rd libraries. The build.gradle looks like below:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.*']) 
    compile 'some library:1.3.2'
    compile 'some other library:1.3.4'
}
```

The library can be compiled freely and finely, and then I push them in to local Maven. Everything fine!

Now I create a client application just for a sample of my library. What confusion is that I must do follow:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.*']) 
    compile 'mylibrary:1.0'
    compile 'some library:1.3.2'
    compile 'some other library:1.3.4'
}
```

Which means to include the two 3rd libraries. Otherwise I must get errors "NoClassFound" which relevant to the two libraries.

You know the

```
compile 'mylibrary:1.0'
```

is the meaning to include my library, but why should I include the other twos which were used by "mylibrary"? Could I avoid that and just  -compile 'mylibrary:1.0' ?

Comment: Please show how you are configuring your POM for `mylibrary` and how you are pushing it to your Maven repository. If you are using something like the `maven` plugin for Gradle, it should add dependencies to your POM automatically, in which case you would not need to duplicate the `some library` and `some other library` lines in the demo app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven't created any POM files and just run command 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../Framework-release.aar -DgroupId=DgroupId -DartifactId=DartifactId -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=aar
Sorry I am new to maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved project with the help of @CommonsWare
Check out

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

To make a pom.xml self and done.